# Trouble with SWAP on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, swap, fstab

I created an AWS m3.large instance. It comes with a single 32GB SSD. During the creation process, I added a second drive for the system. I picked the second drive for the system: xvda1 and the original 30GB drive, I loaded as xvdb.

When the instance started, I logged on as ubuntu and did the following:

```
fdisk /dev/xvdb
#created two partitions
mkfs -t ext4 /dev/xvdb1
tune2fs -m 0 /dev/xvdb1
mkfs -t ext4 /dev/xvdb2
tune2fs -m 0 /dev/xvdb2
mkdir /swap
mkdir /home/railsapp/tmp
mount /dev/xvdb1 /swap
mount /dev/xvdb2 /home/railsapp/tmp
#create a swap file:
sudo fallocate -l 19000000000 /swap/swapfile
sudo chmod 600 /swap/swapfile

sudo mkswap /swap/swapfile
sudo swapon /swap/swapfile
```

I then verified that swap was on with:

```
sudo swapon -s
```

I then removed the entry for /dev/xvdb and added the following:

```
/dev/xvdb1  /swap                    ext4    defaults    0    2
/dev/xvdb2  /home/installio/tmp      ext4    defaults    0    2
/swap/swapfile none   swap    sw              0       0
```

I then stopped the instance and restarted it. I cannot reconnect. The message I'm getting from the system log is:

```
The disk drive for /swap is not ready yet or not present.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to actually create a swap filesystem via:

```
$ mkswap /swap/swapfile
```

Comment: No. I did, I inadvertently forgot to copy it. Please see my edits. I just tried it again with the same results. Maybe this is not possible if I'm using the drive that came with the system, as in if I have to subdivide it, AWS will not like it